# Are (local) UFD's regular?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

The [Auslander-Buchsbaum Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auslander%E2%80%93Buchsbaum_theorem) states that a regular local ring is a UFD. This result seems miraculous: being a UFD is a very strong condition, and there are plenty of regular rings (i.e. rings where every localization is a regular local ring) which are not UFD's (e.g. $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$).

To what extent is the converse true? Are all UFD's regular? What if we assume it is local?

Comment: UFDs are not even noetherian, forget about regular.

Comment: What if we add that hypothesis? I'm not really familiar with how things work in the non-Noetherian case.

Comment: This is one of those things where if it were true you definitely would have heard about it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rings of the form $K[X_1,\dots,X_n]/(X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2)$ where $K$ is a field of characteristic $\ne2$, and $n\ge5$ are UFDs, but not regular. (For a local (counter)example localize at the maximal ideal $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$.)

Comment: Great example! Is it easy to see why it's a UFD?

Comment: @Dorebell Not really! (Look for Klein-Nagata Theorem.)